# What would be the shortest translation for 'Home Delivery' on a restaurant flyer?

Tags: translation, usage

`送饭上门` is what I have now, but for aesthetic reasons I would like to have a 2 character word. Is `送饭` enough on a restaurant flyer (that's the context I am working with) or do I need the whole four character expression?

Comment: You might want to check the enormous amount of [fliers](https://www.google.com.hk/search?newwindow=1&es_sm=93&biw=2133&bih=1013&tbm=isch&sa=1&q=%E5%A4%96%E5%8D%96%20%E4%BC%A0%E5%8D%95&oq=%E5%A4%96%E5%8D%96%20%E4%BC%A0%E5%8D%95&gs_l=img.3...716064.720286.0.720531.20.12.0.0.0.0.405.704.2-1j0j1.2.0....0...1c.1j4.58.img..19.1.299.Qh-MGd1TtUk) to see how they do it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

送餐 will be the appropriate translation for this case. :)

Comment: Thanks, this one looks good. For some reason my dictionaries don't list this word.

Answer (score 2):

If you are working for a eatery, "外卖" is more native because you need to get out of the building to bring your customers food.

"送餐" usually appears in hotels or somewhere else like that. It's a bit formal because the food is prepared by advanced chefs and they are finely laid out but they are just sent to your room.

"送饭" is the worst, I suppose.

Comment: Thank you, I'm going to do some research on your suggestion.

Comment: Notice that in China, some fastfood restaurant has some special name for their home delivery service. 

McDonald: 麦乐送; 
Pizza Hut: 必胜宅急送; 
KFC: 肯德基宅急送; 
永和大王: 大王送.